# Image inside exam environment above question

Tags: graphics, floats, formatting, exam

I am wondering how can I fix the constant problem in inserting an image for a question. When I insert the image, I always have the image being above the question number. I want the question number to come first and then below it the inserted figure. What is a simple way to fix this? Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}%,answers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    % for plots

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6
auto title/.style={     title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}


\question

\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{10.png}
\end{center}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to load `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and then put `valign=t` in the options of `\includegraphics`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}%,answers
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    % for plots

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6
auto title/.style={     title=(\AlphAlph{\pgfplots@group@current@plot})
    }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}


\question
%\leavevmode %% you may need it if no text comes here
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{center}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

If you don't have text/content immediately after `\question` then it is better to put `\leavevmode` there.

[image]

On the other habd, you can lower the picture by

```
\begin{center}
 \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}}
\end{center}
```

without having the need for `adjustbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Very briefly:

```
\question\mbox{}

\includegraphics{...}
```

[image: number first]

Comment: What is the syntax to insert the image? I tried putting in \mbox{image.png} and it just produced text.

Comment: I just put `\mbox{}` after `\question`. I left the image where it was. But [Harish Kumar's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215465/) is more sophisticated and gives a much less crude-looking result.

Comment: @1028 Forgot to ping you...